# Error during getting CCompilerDriver

Tags: compile, windows, ccompilerdriver, version-11.3

I have Window 10, Mathematica 11.3 and Visual Studio Community 2013 (Update 5). If I try to get the package CCOmpilerDriver`, I get follow error:

```
Needs["CCompilerDriver`"]
```

> Import::utf8badlead: Input is not a valid UTF8 byte sequence. Continuation byte 129 is expected to be a leading byte.
>
> Import::jsonhintposition: An error occurred at line 9:22

And if you execute such a line of code:

```
<<"CCompilerDriver`CCompilerDriverBase`"
```

> Import::utf8badlead: Input is not a valid UTF8 byte sequence. Continuation byte 129 is expected to be a leading byte.
>
> Import::jsonhintposition: An error occurred at line 9:22
>
> FilterRules::rep: CCompilerDriver`CCompilerDriverBase`Private`CommonCompilerOptions is not a valid replacement rule.
>
> Join::heads: Heads List and FilterRules at positions 1 and 2 are expected to be the same.
>
> FilterRules::rep: CCompilerDriver`CCompilerDriverBase`Private`CommonCompilerOptions is not a valid replacement rule.
>
> Join::heads: Heads List and FilterRules at positions 1 and 2 are expected to be the same.
>
> FilterRules::rep: CCompilerDriver`CCompilerDriverBase`Private`CommonCompilerOptions is not a valid replacement rule.
>
> General::stop: Further output of FilterRules::rep will be suppressed during this calculation.
>
> Join::heads: Heads List and FilterRules at positions 1 and 2 are expected to be the same.
>
> General::stop: Further output of Join::heads will be suppressed during this calculation.

How to fix it? An error in the code of the СCompilerDriver?

Comment: We have discussed this in chat a couple of weeks ago. I am convinced that this is a bug, so please do report it to Wolfram Support. I believe the bug is triggered only when Windows is set to use a non-English language.

Comment: See around here: https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/45172407#45172407

Comment: I also thought that this was a mistake. But I can't even understand what the problem is

Answer (score 8, accepted):

***Please use the fix [from @ilian's answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/176286/12) instead!!***

---

#### The underlying problem

I think the underlying problem is with the RawJSON importer.  JSON is required to be UTF8.  But a character encoding like UTF8 only makes sense when reading from a file, not when reading from a string (using `ImportString`) that is already interpreted and doesn't have an encoding.

Here's a demonstration of what I believe is going wrong:

```
In[21]:= ImportString["\"jó\"", "RawJSON"]

During evaluation of In[21]:= Import::utf8incompletesequence: Input is not a valid UTF8 byte sequence. The final multibyte sequence is incomplete.

During evaluation of In[21]:= Import::jsonhintposandchar: An error occurred near character '"', at line 1:5

Out[21]= $Failed
```

The RawJSON importer seems to be interpreting the string as a byte-sequence instead of a character sequence.

We can change the string into a form that it will accept:

```
In[23]:= ExportString["\"jó\"", "Text", CharacterEncoding -> "UTF8"]    
Out[23]= "\"jÃ\.b3\""
```

Now it's happy:

```
In[24]:= ImportString[
 ExportString["\"jó\"", "Text", CharacterEncoding -> "UTF8"],
 "RawJSON"
 ]

Out[24]= "jó"
```

#### A possible workaround

I have not tested the following workaround as I am not using Windows at this moment, so I couldn't even reproduce the problem you see in a direct way.

However, I believe the following may work.  *Do this **only** with version 11.3.0 on Windows!!*

Open the folder where the VS driver is using

```
SystemOpen@FileNameJoin[{$InstallationDirectory, "SystemFiles", "Components", "CCompilerDriver"}]
```

You should see the file `VisualStudioCompiler.m`. Make a backup and open it with a text editor. Find line 384, which should be:

```
$vsInfo := $vsInfo = If[$vswhereWorks, ImportString[$vswhereOutput, "RawJSON"], False]
```

Change it to

```
$vsInfo := $vsInfo = If[$vswhereWorks, ImportString[ExportString[$vswhereOutput, "Text", CharacterEncoding -> "UTF8"], "RawJSON"], False]
```

Restart Mathematica and try loading the C compiler driver again. Does it work now?

Comment: Many thanks! I also tried to find the problem in this file

Comment: @KirillBelov Did it work though? As I said, I cannot actually test this.

Comment: I can check it in a few hours and sure I will write here about results

Comment: It really solved the problem, once again many thanks!!

Answer (score 6):

This has been fixed by a paclet update.

Windows 11.3 installations will be automatically updated over the next few days.

To get the new paclet immediately, try

```
PacletSiteUpdate /@ PacletSites[];
PacletUpdate["CCompilerDriver"]
```

Comment: Is it for Windows only? I was just curious about what fix was used (I'm on OS X).

Comment: Windows only. The fix uses a recent vswhere update by Microsoft that supports UTF-8 output.

Comment: I think that `ImportString[..., "RawJSON"]` is still broken, though. It should not try to re-interpret characters in the string according to some encoding. A string is not a byte sequence but an (already interpreted) character sequence.

Comment: The importer insists on valid JSON, that means UTF-8.

Comment: You're right that valid JSON *file* must be UTF8, but only a file (i.e. a byte sequence) has an encoding. A Mathematica *string* does not have an encoding. A string is a sequence of characters, not a sequence of bytes.

Comment: If I type an `ő`, I expect it to be treated as the character "ő" by any function that deals with strings, and not as some number (245 according to ISO8859-2 or 337 according to Unicode).  The problem comes from Mma strings also being used to represent arbitrary byte sequences.  Hopefully that function will be fully replaced by `ByteArray` soon and strings can be finally real strings regardless of what function we're using them with.